# How to add the new contacts on android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-2.2-froyo

I need to add the new contacts on android 2.2 version.

How to add the all fields like Firstname, Lastname, URL, Nickname, IM, Addresses and mobile number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

The process involves some steps, as you would insert the name contact+name first, then field  by field.

Example for phone number:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
...
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber);
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Phone.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Additionally, have a read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html